# Add cron job using php code

Tags: php, linux, cron

I am trying set cron job from php code:

```
file_put_contents('mycrontab.txt', '* * * * *  /usr/bin/php /home2/blabla/public_html/executable_file.php');

echo exec('crontab mycrontab.txt');
```

The above code not starts cron job, because when I am trying get current cron jobs

```
var_dump( shell_exec("crontab -l") );
```

result is `NULL`

P.S.   Sorry if this question is very dumb, I am not know almost nothing about linux commands, including cron jobs.

Comment: @JohnConde,  examples (code) in my question, is exactly  from  the question, which you marked as duplicate, I am trying add cron job as showed `ajreal's` answer, though I can't start cron job. because asked I this question again

Comment: FYI, `exec()` has a return value and two optionals arguments to collect error info. And many programs dump messages to stderr.